# how to set background color only for last bar in d3 multibar chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, extjs5

[image of bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV66j.jpg)Spacing and background color the last bar from D3 bar chart?
This may be a simple question, but if we have a bar chart which is built using D3.js then how can I decorate just the last bar?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code showing how you've built the chart? This will make it easier to show you how to do this

Comment: Can you attach a jsfiddle link or something for this ?